# Why isn't my jquery main menu header not sliding with the nav in IE edge and 10?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I am trying to get the jquery main menu header to slide with the nav when user clicks on the hamburger button. In Chrome, Safari and FF, this works fine, but in IE edge and 10, the header stays in place while the rest of the content slides to the right, so the top section of the nav is cut off. Anyone knows why?

Thanks

My code:

```
<nav id="my-menu" class="visible-xs">
        <ul>
            <li class="Selected"><a href="index-privacy-1.html">Privacy & Security</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cookies, Ads & More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume Security</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Email Scams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a>
                <ul class="Vertical">
                    <li><a href="faq-monster.html">About Monster</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-data-collection.html">Data Collection</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-data-usage.html">Data Usage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-data-sharing.html">Data Sharing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-data-storage.html">Data Storage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-cookies.html">Cookies & Tracking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-advertising.html">Advertising</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-account.html">Account Profile & Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-email.html">Email & Other Communications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-safeguarding.html">Safeguarding Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-jobapp.html">Job Application Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq-privacystandard.html">Privacy Standards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/mp6hub1z/)

Comment: We need the whole javascript & css related.... maybe even jsfiddle or a snippet in the question ?

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/mp6hub1z/

Comment: The thing is that you didn't include styles or js...

Comment: Please use the jsfiddle that I posted above.

Comment: I just did, and there is not styles or javascript, are you sure is that version?

Comment: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/mp6hub1z/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://media.newjobs.com/mm/redux/CMSPages/leftSideImgPlaceholder1.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."

Comment: Hi Toni, I added external javascript, there's no javascript besides that. I didn't add any styling as the page is company confidential.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you then... ( if can't reproduce the problem... )